# Send mails, using SQL Server database mail, programmaticaly

Tags: .net, sql-server, email

Is there an API to use the mail functionality (included in SQL Server) within a .Net program ?

Can I do it without using the stored procedures ?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question a bit more. Is it that you want to call SQL server API from .Net code for mailing something?

Answer (score 1):

try using System.Mail and system.net.mail but you have to configure mail settings for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SQL Server Database Mail set up, you have an SMTP profile.

This means you can use the [inbuilt .net classes](http://MailMessage) to send mail using the same SMTP profile.

Some basic code:

```
var message = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body)
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mySMTPserver.intra.net");
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtpClient.Send(message);
```